# Distinguish if zip one Single with other based on if statement

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I am subscribing to two Singles which are zipped:

```
 firstRepository.sync(id)
      .zipWith(secondRepository.sync(id))
```

Now I want to distinguish which of the repositories I want to sync based on a Boolean. So I can make sync on only one repository or if they are both "enabled" perform this zipWith operator on them.

How can I do this in a clean way?

Answer (score 1):

you could:

1. `map` the emission from each repository into another wrapper type that includes that boolean flag
2. in the `zip` function evaluate the boolean flags to determine which repository's value emission to use

something like this:

```
class Repository {
  Single<Integer> sync(String id) {
    return Single.just(Integer.valueOf(id));
  }
}

class State {
  final int value;
  final boolean active;

  State(int value, boolean active) {
    this.value = value;
    this.active = active;
  }
}

final Repository firstRepository = new Repository();
final Repository secondRepository = new Repository();

final Single<State> firstEmission =
    firstRepository
        .sync(...)
        .map(value -> new State(value, true)); // <-- boolean for firstRepository

final Single<State> secondEmission =
    secondRepository
        .sync(...)
        .map(value -> new State(value, false)); // <-- boolean for secondRepository

firstEmission.zipWith(secondEmission, (first, second) -> {
  if(first.active && !second.active) {
    // firstRepository is active so use its emission...
    return first.value;

  } else if(!first.active && second.active) {
    // secondRepository is active so use its emission...
    return second.value;

  } else if(first.active && second.active) {
    // both repositories are active, so apply some special logic...
    return first.value + second.value;

  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException("No active repository!");
  }
})
    .subscribe();
```